# When and how does spark distribute partitions on executors

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

How does spark assign a partition to an executor.

When I ran the following lines in spark shell with 1 driver and 5 executors:

```
> var data = sc.textFile("file") // auto generates 2 partitions
> data.count()                   // materialize partitions on two nodes
> data = data.repartition(10)    // repartition data.count()            
> data.count()                   // 10 partitions still on original 2 nodes
```

After repartitioning, the 10 partitions still lies on the original two nodes (out of 5). This seems very inefficient, because 5 tasks are repeatedly run on each of the node containing the partitions instead of evenly distributed across nodes. The inefficiency is most obvious for iterative tasks which repeat many times on the same rdds.

So my question is, how does spark decide which node has which partition, and is there a way we can force data to be moved to other nodes?

Comment: You talk about two nodes but you have have one Executor, which doesn't make much sense. Which he are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, just edited. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Are you having problems with Sparks task distribution? Or is this a general question? How many cores does each Executor have?

Comment: I assume number of tasks is the same as number of rdd partitions? When running tasks, because my 10 partitions are located on 2 nodes, then 10 tasks are run on two nodes, which is less efficient than 5 nodes each have 2 partitions, and each node run two tasks. So I'm wondering how does spark decide which partition goes to which node.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/8280 could help...

Comment: @Yituo were you able to answer this question? i'm facing performance issues and would like to know:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67133177/how-spark-distributes-partitions-to-executors

Answer (score 0):

I am just providing a guess here to show the logic (not necessarily what is really happening).

Lets assume your file is not really large, i.e. it fits inside 1 block of HDFS. And assume that block is replicated to 2 nodes. If you would want to do processing on a 3rd node then it would mean you need to copy it. Since count is a relatively fast calculation, it could be that the time it takes to process the task is relatively small. 
Spark might have decided that it would be better to wait and do the processing locally rather than shuffle the data to other nodes (You can configure this parameter).

Comment: Do you know how can I configure such that it would shuffle? I want do a repetitive iterative task, therefore shuffle is needed