# How spark distributes partitions to executors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a performance issue and after analyzing Spark web UI i found what it seems to be data skewness:
[image]

Initially i thought partitions were not evenly distributed, so i performed an analysis of rowcount per partitions, but it seems normal(with no outliers):
[how to manually run pyspark's partitioning function for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132572/how-to-manually-run-pysparks-partitioning-function-for-debugging)

But the problem persists and i see there is one executor processing most of the data:

[image]

So the hypothesis now is **partitions are not evenly distributed across executors**, question is: **how spark distributes partitions to executors?** and **how can i change it to solve my skewness problem?**

The code is very simple:

```
hive_query = """SELECT ... FROM <multiple joined hive tables>"""
df = sqlContext.sql(hive_query).cache()
print(df.count())
```

**Update** after posting this question i performed further analysis and found that there 3 tables that cause this, if they are removed the data is evenly distributed in the executors and performance improves, so i added the spark sql hint /*+  BROADCASTJOIN(<table_name>) */ and it worked, performance is much better now, but the question remains:

**why do this tables(including a small 6 rows table) cause this uneven distribution across executors when added to the query ?**

Comment: Can you share an example of the code you are trying to execute? It seems that only 4 partitions are created while you want many more so the workload can be distributed more evenly.

Comment: You really need to post the code that was running when you took your screenshots in order for people to help answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are reading data from HDFS the number of partitions depends on the number of blocks you are reading. From the images attached it looks like your data is not distributed evenly across the cluster. Try repartitioning your data and increase tweak the number of cores and executors.

If you are repartitioning your data, the hash partitioner is returning a value which is more common than other can lead to data skew.

If this is after performing join, then your data is skewed.

Comment: Indeed, it is after performing a join, i identified the table in the join that causes this, is it something that can be solved via spark code? or is it something solvable using hdfs balancer for that table?

Comment: Checkout broadcast join and key salting. These two techniques can solve data skewness.

Answer (score 3):

`repartition()` will not give you to evenly distributed the dataset as Spark internally uses `HashPartitioner`. To put your data evenly in all partitions then in my point of view Custom Partitioner is the way.

In this case you need to extend the `org.apache.spark.Partitioner` class and use your own logic instead of `HashPartition`. To achieve this we need to convert the `RDD` to `PairRDD`.

Found below blog post which will be help you in your case:
https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/custom-partitioning-spark-datasets-25cbd4e2d818

Thanks